# I have two arrays if "Cost" and "Sell" price about many fruits. How calculate the diference using a "smart" function filter and map?

Tags: javascript, sorting, arraylist, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

```
in Vue3 composition API, I have 2 arrays 
const fruitsSellerPrice = [
{id: 1, name: apple, priceSeller: '10.90'},
{id: 2, name: banana, priceSeller: '11.20'},
{id: 3, name: orange, priceSeller: '12.30'},
{id: 4, name: framboesa, priceSeller: '13.90'}}];

const fruitsBuyPrice = [
{id: 1, name: apple, priceBuy: '6.90'},
{id: 2, name: banana, priceBuy: '6.20'},
{id: 3, name: orange, priceBuy '7.30'},
{id: 4, name: framboesa, priceBuy: '16.90'}}];
```

I would like to know how can I do a "smart" filter that return te difference by "name" and order High to low or Low to High, priceSell - PriceBuy...

I have me a function with very big lines.. something is wrong....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like following snippet:

```js
const fruitsSellerPrice = [{id: 1, name: 'apple', priceSeller: '10.90'},{id: 2, name: 'banana', priceSeller: '11.20'},{id: 3, name: 'orange', priceSeller: '12.30'},{id: 4, name: 'framboesa', priceSeller: '13.90'}]

const fruitsBuyPrice = [{id: 1, name: 'apple', priceBuy: '6.90'},{id: 2, name: 'banana', priceBuy: '6.20'},{id: 3, name: 'orange', priceBuy: '7.30'},{id: 4, name: 'framboesa', priceBuy: '16.90'}]

let sortOrder = true
const res = fruitsSellerPrice.map(f => {
  return {...f, diff: Math.abs((Number(f.priceSeller) - Number(fruitsBuyPrice.find(u => u.id === f.id).priceBuy))).toFixed(2)}
}).sort((a, b) => {
  return sortOrder ? a.diff - b.diff : b.diff - a.diff
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: hi !!! :) !! you again? I was here studing calm your logic... 
thank you again, it´s to "same project" :)

Comment: @Fernanda hey :) did you received my mail?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// find all seller items, and check what the value is in the buy array is and respond with the difference.
const response = fruitsSellerPrice.map( item => 
        ({ ...item, 
          diff: 
            Math.abs( 
              Number(
                fruitsBuyPrice.find(
                  buy=>buy.name === item.name).priceBuy) 
              - Number(item.priceSeller).toFixed(2)) 
              })
        ).sort((a,b)=>b.diff-a.diff) 
// for asc, do a.diff - b.diff
```

Comment: Doesn't "order High to low or Low to High".